# Two conditions loop python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have data as below

```
lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
```

I need to replace all parts with `@` or `&`. I do like this

```
new = []
simbol1 = '@'
simbol2 = '&'
for item in lst:
    if simbol1 not in item:
        if simbol2 not in item:
            new.append(item)
```

But is there more simple way for this loop?
I tried like this

```
lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
new = []
simbol1 = '@'
simbol2 = '&'
for item in lst:
    if any([simbol1 not in item , simbol2 not in item]):
        new.append(item)
```

But i get

```
new
['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
```

What is a correct way to use multiple conditions in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine two `if`s:

```
if simbol1 not in item and simbol2 not in item:
    new.append(item)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `list comprehension` & merge the two `if`'s as follows:

```
>>> lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
>>> new_lst = [l for l in lst if '@' not in l and '&' not in l]
>>> new_lst
['abs']
>>>
```

---

You can also use `all()` instead of multiple `if`s like follows:

```
>>> lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
>>> new_lst = [l for l in lst if all(x not in l for x in ['@','&'])]
>>> new_lst
['abs']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
new = []
simbol1 = '@'
simbol2 = '&'
for item in lst:
    if all([simbol1 not in item , simbol2 not in item]):
       new.append(item)
print (new)
```

Comment: You need to replace any with all.

Answer (score 1):

[`Functionally`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), you could do

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: all(f not in x for f in ['@', '&']), lst))
```

as an explanation, the `lambda` function ensures that none of the forbidden `f` characters are in string by `filtering` out all values that evaluate to `False`. `filter` returns a generator, so one can make that a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['abs', '@abs', '&abs']
out_lst = [el for el in lst if '@' not in el and '&' not in el]
print(out_lst) # ['abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close to correct; the only problem is that you got the negation backward.

This:

```
if any([simbol1 not in item , simbol2 not in item]):
```

… is asking "are any of these are not in the item?" Just as in English, that's true if one is not in the item, but the other is in the item, which isn't what you want. You only want it to be true if *neither* is in the item.

In other words, you want either "are *all* of these not in the item?"

```
if all([simbol1 not in item, simbol2 not in item]):
```

… or "are *none* of these in the item?"

```
if not any([simbol1 in item, simbol2 in item]):
```

---

However, when you only have a fixed list of two things like this, it's usually easier to use `and` or `or` instead of `any` or `all`—again, just like in English:

```
if symbol1 not in item and simbol2 not in item:
```

… or:

```
if not (simbol1 in item or simbol2 in item):
```

If, on the other hand, you had a whole bunch of symbols to check, or a list of them that you couldn't even know until runtime, you'd want a loop:

```
if all(simbol not in item for simbol in (simbol1, simbol2)):

if not any(simbol in item for simbol in (simbol1, simbol2)):
```